# Redirecting users signing in with social accounts

Tags: python, django

I am using Django allauth for sign up and social authentication. For users signing up with there email, they are redirected normally to their profile based on their username as the slug. For example, something like this:

**views.py**

```
class RegisterView(SignupView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'oauth/auth_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect('profiles:Index', slug=form.cleaned_data['username'])
```

The user is redirected to the profiles app which contains an Index view that displays their profile based on the slug (their username inputted). This works correctly, however, when I try to do social sign in with Facebook or Google for example, it redirects me to /accounts/profile/# which is the default Django profiles page. I want them to be redirected to the profiles app, which is `/profiles/{their username}` How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think this usecase/situation is described on their (`django-allauth`) documentation. You can check it [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects).

Basically you need to create a custom adapter class (that inherits from `allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter` or `allauth.socialaccount.adapter.DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`, depending on the case) with that functionality and them point to it using the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` variable in the settings.

Comment: When I do this I get an error saying: `AttributeError: 'SocialAccountAdapter' object has no attribute 'is_safe_url'`

Answer (score 0):

For errors like

> AttributeError: 'SocialAccountAdapter' object has no attribute
>   'is_safe_url'

If you create custom adapter inheriting `allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter`, set `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` in settings.py.

If it's `allauth.socialaccount.adapter.DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`, set `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER` in settings.py